# asp-net 1.0, Docker and Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, asp.net-core-1.0

I am currently trying to port a service across to asp-net 1.0 and get it up and running in a local Kubernetes cluster, or even a single node (Kubernetes Master and 1 minion). I have successfully managed the first part and had my service running in kestrel using Docker within a Boot2Docker VM and also Centos7. I am now trying to get my container up and running in Kubernetes. I have been trawling Google for a guide in doing this and everywhere I turn this seems a rather convoluted task. Has anyone else achieved this and have any useful guides/links?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path, just a few additional steps:

1. Package your app into a docker image, use the aspnet base image and add your code (https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/)
2. Push your image up to a docker repo
3. Deploy that image to your cluster

The basic rule of thumb is just get your app dockerized then you can run it in k8s.